# Breaking out of a 'do while' loop in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a 'do while' loop in Perl, and I need to break out if in the middle. I see `last label;` is how I break out of loop, but I can't figure out where to add label. Here is my sample code.

```
my $count = 5;

do {
    print $count;

    if ( $count == 2 ) { last TAG; }

    $count--;

} while ( $count > 0 );

TAG: print "out";
```

The above fails with *"cannot find label"*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use the [statement modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) form of [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html):

> [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) `BLOCK` does *not* count as a loop, so the loop control statements [`next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html), [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html), or [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) cannot be used to leave or restart the block. See [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) for alternative strategies.

Instead, I recommend using a [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) loop.

```
my $count = 5;

while ( $count > 0 ) {
    print $count;
    last if $count == 2;
    $count--;
}

print "out";
```

Outputs:

```
5432out
```

If you need a construct that will always run one time before testing a condition, then use a `while` loop of this form:

```
while (1) {
    ...

    last if COND;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I checked this works with while loop. But in my actual code, I need do..while, because I need to repeat the loop only when a condition fails. If nothing fails, I just execute the do loop once and get out.

Comment: If you need to run a loop once even if the COND fails, then use the form I just added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this out now.

Comment: `{ ... ; redo if COND }` also works. On the plus side, it doesn't look like an infinite loop. On the minus side, it doesn't immediately look like a loop at all :)

Comment: That's why `while (1) {` is superior.  It communicates the fact that it's a loop immediately.  And because the exit condition isn't immediately stated, one knows to look at the end of the block for the `last` statement.

Comment: @hobbs, Re "On the plus side, it doesn't look like an infinite loop", Infinite loops never loop infinitely, so looking like an infinite loop is not a problem. Either way, I added a non-infinite bottom tested loop to my answer.

Comment: I switched to while loop and cant last correctly now. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Thanks. But I'd be interested to know why the do-while loop doesn't count as a ... loop!

Comment: @e2-e4 Fair question.  The answer is, it was a judgement call of the implementors of the language.

When it comes down to it, a do {} block is not inherently a loop.  It's only if one happens to add the statement modifier while to it that it can be treated as one. 
 

There's something to be said for the top/down readability of code, and not having to scroll to the end of a block to observe that loop control constructs should apply to this particular do {} block.

Perhaps it was a bad call, but that ship has sailed a long time ago.

Answer (score 7):

```
do BLOCK while COND;
```

is just `do BLOCK` with a [statement modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) attached. While it is special-cased to be bottom-tested, it is not a flow control statement like `while (COND) BLOCK`. `last` and friends only affect flow control statements, not statement modifiers.

```
$ perl -e'last while 1;'
Can't "last" outside a loop block at -e line 1.
```

One trick is to add a bare loop.

```
do {{
   ...;
   next if ...;
   ...;
}} while COND;
```

or

```
{
   do {
      ...;
      last if ...;
      ...;
   } while COND;
}
```

But that's fragile, error-prone and misleading. I prefer using an infinite loop as it is much safer and clearer.

```
while (1) {
   ...;
   next if ...;
   last if ...;
   ...;
   last if !COND;
}
```

If you really dislike the infinite loop, you could also use the following, but I consider it more complex. (Two extra statements.)

```
for (my $loop=1; $loop; $loop=COND) {
    ...;
    next if ...;
    last if ...;
    ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I switched to the infinite loop with a last.

Answer (score 2):

You can use goto instead of last.

```
my $count = 5;

do {
    print $count;

    if ( $count == 2 ) { goto TAG; }

    $count--;

} while ( $count > 0 );

TAG: print "out";
```

Comment: I see. I will keep this in mind for future. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your tag is mis-placed. You haven't named the loop itself, you've simply placed a label somewhere that `goto LABEL` could see. If you want to break out of the loop, you'll have to label the loop.

Additionally, `do { ... } while` doesn't count as a loop. To make a loop that can be labeled, place it within its own set of braces:

```
TAG: { do {
  body of the loop goes here.
  last TAG if $condition;
} while( COND ) }
```